# Search filter Logic

Tags: sql-server, database, search, filter

I have a web site with search that uses filters. So whenever someone search, search is conducted to bring search results but then the same search is repeated again to populate each filter. Reason i run the same search to populate filters is because each search filter also displays the count of products in that search. So if i have 5 filters.... then the search is performed 6 times. 1 time to bring the body of the search and 5 times to populate each filter.

This is a huge waste of resources. What can i do to optimize this process? Because of the fact that we sell one of a kind products, we cannot pre-populate Popular searches. We have to go to the database to get the actual live inventory.

I cannot populate dataset with complete search results because search can literally bring millions of products.

Please give ideas.

Thank You

Kevin

Comment: Why don't you populate all the filters from the one search result?

Comment: Which technology stack you are using? It sounds like a query n+1 problem. why is the number of products important?

Comment: Need more information on the current implementation.